# Google actions account linking different URL's in DEBUG- sharedDebugInfo-debugInfo

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am new to actions on google and I am trying to explore account linking feature.

I was able to create a project under google actions and link it to dialog flow. Enabled account linking and everything worked fine.

Now I created a second project and followed the same process. This time account linking card is not showing on my google home app. 
When I tried to check the difference between two project what I found that the account linking messages are different.

For working action this is the message:

```
It looks like your <Project name> account is not linked yet. You can link <Project name> to your Google Account from the Google Home app.
```

For not working action, this is the message:

```
It looks like your my test app account is not linked yet.
```

It does not contain the second half of the message.

And also when I tried these actions on simulator, under DEBUG sharedDebugInfo-debugInfo the URL's are different.

For working action:

```
https://gala-demo.appspot.com/app?login_hint=google email id&service_id=projectid_dev&scope=openid&return_url=https://www.google.com/
```

For not working action:

```
https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?account_name=google email id&provider=projectid_dev&scopes=openid&return_url=https://www.google.com/
```

Can anyone help me understand why my second action is not working and why is it behaving different from the first one?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, some times it is working some times not.